# Add button to Tkinter Window panel before minimise, maximise buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-menu

I have developed a Tkinter GUI and need to add a button in the GUI window top panel, next to the minimise, maximise and close buttons. The button then calls a function. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter doesn't have any support to do what you want. You'll have to find some sort of platform-specific library to alter what is shown in the window border.

Your only other option is to turn off the window border provided by your OS with `overrideredirect`, and then create your own border with whatever controls you want. This requires a lot of work because you also have to write the code for moving and resizing the window, but it's possible.